# Android, How to set animation listener for view group?

Tags: android, animation, listener, viewgroup

I have an image view which acts as menu. When user click it a view group (including 5 other image view) will slide from left to right. When user click on menu again view group slides from right to left.

I can simulate this behavior but after sliding right to left I expect to not see view group however view group will put on its place. I tried to use `LinearLayout.setVisibiliy(View.Invisible)` but at that moment i couldn't see sliding right to left animation.

This is my code, any suggestion would be appreciated.

menu_open.xml

```
<layoutAnimation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:delay="10%"
    android:animation="@anim/slide_out" />
```

slide_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

menu_close.xml

```
<layoutAnimation 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:delay="10%"
    android:animation="@anim/slide_in" />
```

slide_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_01" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMenu" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_03" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_04" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_05" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_06" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CD"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_07" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView ivMenu;
    private Animation animate;
    private LinearLayout groupLayout;
    private boolean menuState = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        groupLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        groupLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ivMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMenu);
        animate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animate);
        ivMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ivMenu.startAnimation(animate);
                runFadeOutAnimationOn(MainActivity.this, ivMenu);

                if(!menuState) {
                     groupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     runExpandMenuAnimation(groupLayout, MainActivity.this);
                } else {
                    runCollapseMenuAnimation(groupLayout, MainActivity.this);
//                   groupLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                menuState = !menuState;
                Log.i("Menu state", "" + menuState);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void runExpandMenuAnimation(ViewGroup panel, Context ctx) {
        LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ctx, R.anim.menu_open);
        panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    }

    public static void runCollapseMenuAnimation(ViewGroup panel, Context ctx) {
        LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ctx, R.anim.menu_close);
        panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
  }

    public static Animation runFadeOutAnimationOn(Activity ctx, View target) {
          Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.fade_out);
          target.startAnimation(animation);

          return animation;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. In this case we should use `aViewGroup.setLayoutAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()...)` and override its methods.

Therefore I added:

```
 groupLayout.setLayoutAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if(menuState)
                    groupLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                menuState = !menuState;
                Log.i("Menu state", "" + menuState);
            }
        });
```