# how to check if an application is killed during an animation in android

Tags: android

i have to make an application in which it starts with an animation and if we click the back button then it should return back to application manager.But what i have made in it if u click back button during that animation then it goes to application manager but after a second or two the first page(the one after this animation comes up).

Can anyone help??

This is the animation..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.load_icon);
        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.load_page);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        im.startAnimation(rotate);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        P1.class);
                startActivity(nextPageIntent);

            }
        }, 3000);

    }
```

Comment: means you want to open first page after animation is stop?

Comment: actually sir i think that if i click on the back button the animation does not stop but continues in the background.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/ check this link

Comment: implement **AnimationListener** put your code in **onAnimationEnd** method

Comment: can you please tel that if we click back button which function is invoked like onPause() onResume()...

Comment: see my animation is working properly but if suddenly in want stop animation it is not happening

Answer (score 0):

The first page opens because you have added
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    P1.class);
            startActivity(nextPageIntent);

        }
    }, 3000);
```

This launches the activity.For knowing if the animation has stopped use AnimationListener. More details here about animation listener
[Android, How to set animation listener for view group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328779/android-how-to-set-animation-listener-for-view-group)

Answer (score 0):

You just added animation to one image view thats all, you do not doing anything with animation. The problem is, you started one thread to start activity P1 after 3 seconds. That thread only starting P1 activity. Try this and try to avoid `killProcess()`,

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        XmlParserActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextPageIntent);
            }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
    }
   /* @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

This is the answer