# How do I keep animated components from "bouncing back" to their original positions after animation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

I want to make a `CardView` placed at the bottom of the window slide down when you switch modes, and slide back up when you go back into normal mode. The problem is that while the animation works fine, the card immediately reappears in the same spot it was in after the animation finishes. How do I get it to stay/freeze until I want to make it come back?

Here's my animation code for hiding the card (in `card_hide_ani.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

...and the method that hides the card in `MainActivity.java` (called from button tap)

```
    void HideCard(Context context) {
        CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        Animation cardAni = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.card_hide_ani);
        cardView.startAnimation(cardAni);
    }
```

*(I'd also like to animate the card's transparency/alpha, although I'm not entirely sure if that'll work for both the card and it's embedded components. I'll deal with that later, but right now I just want to get this working.)*

Like I said, the animation part works fine, but the card "bounces" right back to where it was. I can't find anything that indicates why, and so far it's been frustrating. I'm assuming that I should have done it some other way, but I can't figure out what to do or how to go about doing it. Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: App running on Android Emulator (Android 10 (Q) on Windows 10)]
*Visual demonstration of problem*

Comment: So you want to hide the whole CardView which has TextView and FAB child's once the animation is completed?

Comment: Yeah, the entire CardView. I want it to stay wherever the animation makes it end up, if that makes any sense.

Comment: In your function hideCard() once your animation is completed just hide the CardView using visibility modifiers. And Whenever you want to show the card again set animation and visibility to VISIBLE.

Comment: What about for other things? That FAB is supposed to shrink to show the progress bar behind it when it's tapped and the next window is loading. It doesn't stay shrunk. How do I keep it from resizing?

Comment: I'm afraid i did not understood you completely. But i have found similar solution that fixes your problem. Check this answer : 
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/12329682/7725103

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try custom animation ( this will give you more control over animation), you can try this. I have tried both YAxis animation & Alpha animation together. This will give you context on how we can control item.

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.animation.ValueAnimator
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class MainActivityF : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var downTextView: TextView
    lateinit var upTextView: TextView
    lateinit var cardview: CardView
    private val cardViewOriginalY: Float by lazy { cardview.y }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_f)
        downTextView = findViewById(R.id.down)
        upTextView = findViewById(R.id.up)
        cardview = findViewById(R.id.cardview)

        downTextView.setOnClickListener { animateCardDown() }
        upTextView.setOnClickListener { animateCardUp() }
    }

    private fun animateCardDown() {
        val yAxisAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(cardViewOriginalY, cardViewOriginalY + cardview.height)
        val alphaAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0.5f)
        with(yAxisAnimator) {
            duration = 300L
            addUpdateListener {
                val currentY = it.animatedValue as Float
                cardview.y = currentY
            }
        }

        with(alphaAnimator) {
            duration = 300L
            addUpdateListener {
                val currentAlpha = it.animatedValue as Float
                cardview.alpha = currentAlpha
            }
        }

        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        with(animatorSet) {
            playTogether(yAxisAnimator, alphaAnimator)
            start()
        }
    }

    private fun animateCardUp() {
        val yAxisAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(cardViewOriginalY + cardview.height, cardViewOriginalY)
        val alphaAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.5f, 1.0f)
        with(yAxisAnimator) {
            duration = 300L
            addUpdateListener {
                val currentY = it.animatedValue as Float
                cardview.y = currentY
            }
        }

        with(alphaAnimator) {
            duration = 300L
            addUpdateListener {
                val currentAlpha = it.animatedValue as Float
                cardview.alpha = currentAlpha
            }
        }

        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        with(animatorSet) {
            playTogether(yAxisAnimator, alphaAnimator)
            start()
        }
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="DOWN ANIMATION"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="UP ANIMATION"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to add this line

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

to your xml TranslateAnimation code. Since a TranslateAnimation not really animates the view itself, more like a bitmap representing the View on the screen, without that line the animation does not stay at the wanted position.

For general better and more dynamic animations check out [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator)

This allows you to chain multiple animations together in one line of code, as well as it really animates the View's property itself on the screen, other than the xml TranslateAnimation, which like mentioned above, only moves the pixels on the screen, not the View itself.
This should also get you started with your other (alpha) animation plans.